# Extracting Map values from a List of Maps List[Map[String,Any]]?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

how would you go about pattern matching to extract values from Maps contained in a List ?

So my data is of type `List[Map[String,Any]]` and looks like :

```
List(Map(sequence -> 192, id -> 8697413670252052, type -> List(AimLowEvent, DiscreteEvent), time -> 527638582195))
List(Map(duration -> 143858743, id -> 8702168014834892, sequence -> 195, sessionId -> 8697344444103393, time -> 527780267698, type -> List(SessionCanceled, SessionEnded)), Map(trackingInfo -> Map(trackId -> 14170286, location -> Browse, listId -> cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585, videoId -> 80000778, rank -> 0, row -> 0, requestId -> ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171), id -> 8697344444103393, sequence -> 89, time -> 527636408955, type -> List(Play, Action, Session)), 1)
List(Map(duration -> 142862569, id -> 8702168403395215, sequence -> 201, sessionId -> 8697374208897843, time -> 527780267698, type -> List(SessionCanceled, SessionEnded)), Map(trackingInfo -> Map(trackId -> 14170286, location -> Browse, listId -> cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585, videoId -> 80000778, rank -> 0, row -> 0, requestId -> ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171), id -> 8697374208897843, sequence -> 136, time -> 527637405129, type -> List(Play, Action, Session)), 1)
```

Firstly I would only like to keep records that contain the `Map(trackingInfo -> ..` as the fields that are important to me are in those records, e.g `trackId`. However in those same records I need the outer fields also such as `sequence`

I've tired to flatten the list into a Map by, so I can match on the maps:

```
myList.flatten.toMap
```

However it returns a `java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4 cannot be cast to scala.Tuple2` error.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't get this exception (or the one in comment to Stefano's answer) from code you show. The real reason is likely using `asInstanceOf` or `isInstanceOf` incorrectly somewhere else.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yeh I do use `asInstanceOf[List[Map[String,Any]]` to get the above structure. The original data is nested json.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I think your right, so I gone about dealing with the problem in a different way. If your interested here is my question with regards to parsing the raw json https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787888/parsing-nested-json-using-json4s-and-scala-case-classes

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to achieve, I believe a `filter` will do:

```
// taken from your example and simplified
val list =
  List(
    Map("duration" -> 142862569L, "id" -> 8702168403395215L, "sequence" -> 201, "sessionId" -> 8697374208897843L, "time" -> 527780267698L, "type" -> List("SessionCanceled", "SessionEnded")),
    Map("trackingInfo" -> Map("trackId" -> 14170286L, "location" -> "Browse", "listId" -> "cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585", "videoId" -> "80000778", "rank" -> 0, "row" -> 0, "requestId" -> "ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171"), "id" -> 8697374208897843L, "sequence" -> 136, "time" -> 527637405129L, "type" -> List("Play", "Action", "Session")))

val onlyWithTrackingInfo =
  list.filter(_.contains("trackingInfo"))
```

Printing `onlyWithTrackingInfo` would output the following (prettified):

```
List(
  Map(
    trackingInfo -> Map(trackId -> 14170286, location -> Browse, listId -> cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585, videoId -> 80000778, rank -> 0, row -> 0, requestId -> ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171), 
    id -> 8697374208897843,
    sequence -> 136,
    time -> 527637405129,
    type -> List(Play, Action, Session)
  )
)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, however I keep get this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map`

Comment: perhaps because in my data, `trackingInfo` only occurs in the 2nd Map and never the first like in your data ?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to `collect` any `Map` that consists of the wanted key:

```
def extract(list: List[Map[String, Any]], key: String) = list.collect{
  case m if m.get(key) != None => m
}

val list1: List[Map[String, Any]] = List(
  Map("sequence" -> 192, "id" -> 8697413670252052L, "type" -> List("AimLowEvent", "DiscreteEvent"), "time" -> 527638582195L)
)

val list2: List[Map[String, Any]] = List(
  Map("duration" -> 143858743, "id" -> 8702168014834892L, "sequence" -> 195, "sessionId" -> 8697344444103393L, "time" -> 527780267698L, "type" -> List("SessionCanceled", "SessionEnded")),
  Map("trackingInfo" -> Map("trackId" -> 14170286, "location" -> "Browse", "listId" -> "cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585", "videoId" -> 80000778, "rank" -> 0, "row" -> 0, "requestId" -> "ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171"), "id" -> 8697344444103393L, "sequence" -> 89, "time" -> 527636408955L, "type" -> List("Play", "Action", "Session"))
)

extract(list1, "trackingInfo")
// res1: List[Map[String,Any]] = List()

extract(list2, "trackingInfo")
// res2: List[Map[String,Any]] = List(
//  Map(trackingInfo -> Map(trackId -> 14170286, location -> Browse, listId -> cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585, videoId -> 80000778, rank -> 0, row -> 0, requestId -> ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171), id -> 8697344444103393, sequence -> 89, time -> 527636408955, type -> List(Play, Action, Session))
// )
```